# Как сделать слайдер триггером которого является скролл?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я пытаюсь сделать слайдер который реагирует на скролл. При достижении этого блока со слайдером пользователь должен остановится на нем и скроллить уже только слайдер после окончание слайдов страница дальше скроллится. Я пытался использовать one-page scroll но это кажется там не реализуется (или я не смог). Кроме того пытался использовать gsap тоже не получилось

```js
$(".projects").onepage_scroll({
    sectionContainer: ".item-slide", 
    easing: "ease",                   
    animationTime: 700,             
    pagination: false,               
    updateURL: false,               
    beforeMove: function(index) {

    },  
    afterMove: function(index) {

    },  
    loop: false,                    
    keyboard: true,                 
    responsiveFallback: false,       
    direction: "horizontal"            
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Исправил код, добавил обработчик смены размеров окна.
Оставил комментарии к коду.
Код стал заметно стабильнее.
Вставляйте сколько хотите слайдов в любом направлении.

```js
const presenter = document.querySelector('.presenter');
const slides = [...document.querySelectorAll('.presenter > .slide')].map((element, index) => ({
  index,
  element,
  isFirst: element.classList.contains('first'),
  isLast: element.classList.contains('last'),
  animIn: [...element.classList.values()].filter(cls => /^in-/.test(cls))[0].substr(3),
  animOut: [...element.classList.values()].filter(cls => /^out-/.test(cls))[0].substr(4),
  title: element.querySelector('h2').innerHTML,
  color: null,
  scrollPos: null,
  scrollIn: null,
  scrollOut: null,
}));

let totalScroll;

// Распорка для скролинга
const space = document.createElement('div');
space.classList.add('space');
presenter.appendChild(space);

// Пересчитать слайды
recalculate();

for (let index = 0; index < slides.length; index++) {
  const slide = slides[index];
  // Разукрасим слайды
  slide.element.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
  // Добавим в распорку слайд нужного размера
  const spaceSlide = document.createElement('div');
  spaceSlide.classList.add('slide', ['up', 'down'].includes(slide.animIn) ? 'vert' : 'horiz');
  space.appendChild(spaceSlide);
}

presenter.onscroll = () => reposition();

window.onresize = () => {
  recalculate();
  reposition();
};

// Функция перерасчитывает положения и размеры слайдов
function recalculate() {
  // Расчет
  totalScroll = 0;
  for (let index = 0; index < slides.length; index++) {
    const slide = slides[index];
    slide.scrollPos = totalScroll;
    totalScroll += ['up', 'down'].includes(slide.animOut)
      ? innerHeight
      : ['left', 'right'].includes(slide.animOut)
      ? innerWidth
      : innerHeight;
  }

  space.style.height = totalScroll + 'px';

  for (let index = 0; index < slides.length; index++) {
    const slide = slides[index];
    slide.element.style.top =
      slide.animIn == 'up' ? innerHeight + 'px' : slide.animIn == 'down' ? -innerHeight + 'px' : 0;
    slide.element.style.left =
      slide.animIn == 'left' ? innerWidth + 'px' : slide.animIn == 'right' ? -innerWidth + 'px' : 0;
    slide.scrollIn =
      slide.animIn == 'up' || slide.animIn == 'down'
        ? slide.scrollPos - innerHeight
        : slide.animIn == 'left' || slide.animIn == 'right'
        ? slide.scrollPos - innerWidth
        : slide.scrollPos;
    slide.scrollOut =
      slide.animOut == 'up' || slide.animOut == 'down'
        ? slide.scrollPos + innerHeight
        : slide.animOut == 'left' || slide.animOut == 'right'
        ? slide.scrollPos + innerWidth
        : slide.scrollPos;
  }
}

// Фнкция репозиционирует слайды при сколле
function reposition() {
  let scrollTop = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
  for (let index = 0; index < slides.length; index++) {
    const slide = slides[index];
    let left, top;
    if (slide.scrollIn < scrollTop && scrollTop < slide.scrollOut) {
      // Слайд в пределах видимости
      if (scrollTop < slide.scrollPos) {
        // Следующий слайд
        [left, top] = (
          slide.animIn == 'up'
            ? [0, slide.scrollPos - scrollTop]
            : slide.animIn == 'left'
            ? [slide.scrollPos - scrollTop, 0]
            : slide.animIn == 'right'
            ? [scrollTop - slide.scrollPos, 0]
            : slide.animIn == 'down'
            ? [0, scrollTop - slide.scrollPos]
            : [0, 0]
        ).map(v => `${v}px`);
      } else {
        // Предыдущий слайд
        [left, top] = (
          slide.animOut == 'up'
            ? [0, slide.scrollPos - scrollTop]
            : slide.animOut == 'left'
            ? [slide.scrollPos - scrollTop, 0]
            : slide.animOut == 'right'
            ? [scrollTop - slide.scrollPos, 0]
            : slide.animOut == 'down'
            ? [0, scrollTop - slide.scrollPos]
            : [0, 0]
        ).map(v => `${v}px`);
      }
    } else {
      // Слайд вне диапазона видимости
      if (slide.scrollIn > scrollTop) {
        // Слайд еще впереди
        [left, top] = (
          slide.animIn == 'up'
            ? [0, 0 - innerHeight]
            : slide.animIn == 'left'
            ? [0 - innerWidth, 0]
            : slide.animIn == 'right'
            ? [innerWidth, 0]
            : slide.animIn == 'down'
            ? [0, innerHeight]
            : [0, 0]
        ).map(v => `${v}px`);
      } else if (slide.scrollOut < scrollTop) {
        // Слайд уже позади
        [left, top] = (
          slide.animOut == 'up'
            ? [0, innerHeight]
            : slide.animOut == 'left'
            ? [innerWidth, 0]
            : slide.animOut == 'right'
            ? [0 - innerWidth, 0]
            : slide.animOut == 'down'
            ? [0, 0 - innerHeight]
            : [0, 0]
        ).map(v => `${v}px`);
      }
    }
    Object.assign(slide.element.style, { left, top });
  }
}

presenter.querySelector('.first').style.top = 0;

// Функция возвращает рандомный цввет
function randomColor() {
  // Берем цвета более светлые (>128)
  const red = (128 + ~~(128 * Math.random())).toString(16);
  const grn = (128 + ~~(128 * Math.random())).toString(16);
  const blu = (128 + ~~(128 * Math.random())).toString(16);
  return `#${red}${grn}${blu}`;
}
```

```css
/** @format */
html {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Головной элемент */
.presenter {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
/* Слайд */
.presenter > .slide {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
/* Заголовок слайда */
.presenter > .slide h2 {
  font-size: 5em;
  color: black;
}
/* Слайд в распорке */
.presenter > .space > .slide {
  scroll-snap-align: end;
  scroll-snap-stop: normal;
}
/* Вертикальное позиционирование */
.presenter > .space > .slide.horiz {
  height: 100vw;
}
/* Горизонтальное позиционирование */
.presenter > .space > .slide.vert {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href='data:image/svg+xml,<svg%20xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./presenter.css" />
  </head>
  <body class="presenter">
    <div class="slide first in-up out-up"><h2>1</h2></div>
    <div class="slide in-up out-up"><h2>2</h2></div>
    <div class="slide in-up out-left"><h2>3</h2></div>
    <div class="slide in-left out-left"><h2>4</h2></div>
    <div class="slide in-left out-up"><h2>5</h2></div>
    <div class="slide in-up out-up"><h2>6</h2></div>
    <div class="slide in-up out-right"><h2>7</h2></div>
    <div class="slide in-right out-right"><h2>8</h2></div>
    <div class="slide in-right out-up"><h2>9</h2></div>
    <div class="slide in-up out-up"><h2>10</h2></div>
    <div class="slide in-up out-up last"><h2>11</h2></div>
    <script src="./presenter.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```